# Annotated WS in JBoss

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, glassfish, java-ee-6

I am trying to see the compatibly of different jee6 servers.

With this occasion I did a very basic WS app

http://uploading.com/files/786a932f/HelloWorldWs.war/

It is the most simple one :)

```
 @WebService(serviceName = "HelloWorldWs")
  public class HelloWorldWs {

    /** This is a sample web service operation */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

It works very nice on Glassfish 3.1

http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldWs/HelloWorldWs?wsdl

return the wsdl

but when i try on latest JBoss 7 CR that link is not working anymore despite the war is deployed and  http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldWs works.

My qustion is: is something wrong in what i do or JBoss is not yet ready for WS yet in this light form by using only annotations ?

Thank you !

Comment: I believe you have to be certain your jax-ws.xml file is correct.

Comment: i don't have such file and is not needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue ([JBWS-3276](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-3276)) in JBoss AS 6 (discussion [here](http://community.jboss.org/thread/165696)).

You may have to add an entry to your web.xml as described in the [JBoss 6 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/WebServices_Guide/en-US/html_single/index.html#JBossWS-JAX-WSTools_BottomUp_Using_wsprovide).

*If you find new issues I recommend you [report them](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS) - though refer to the [specs](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2011/04/java-jax-ws-web-services-and-clients.html#ws_doc) and not the Glassfish implementation for the final word on expected behaviour. The web services API is maintained at [jboss.org/jbossws](http://www.jboss.org/jbossws) so it would be best to track these releases for JAX-WS support.*